# Can't read Data input Stream in java IO

Tags: java, io, file-handling

Hi everyone i am practicing with **java data input output stream**. But i don't know how to fix this problem i can write data input stream to my file but can't read it

here is my code:

```
public static void readDataIOStream(){
            DataInputStream dataIn = null;

            int i = 10;
            double d = 1023.56;
            boolean b = true;

            try {
                dataIn = new DataInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream("test.txt"));

                i = dataIn.readInt();
                System.out.println("Reading " + i);
                d = dataIn.readDouble();
                System.out.println("Reading " + d);
                b = dataIn.readBoolean();
                System.out.println("Reading " + b);
                d = dataIn.readDouble();
                System.out.println("Reading " + d);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }try {
                dataIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void writeDataIOStream(){
            DataOutputStream dataOut = null;

            int i = 10;
            double d = 1023.56;
            boolean b = true;

            try {
                dataOut = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.txt"));
                System.out.println("Writing " + i);
                dataOut.write(i);
                System.out.println("Writing " + d);
                dataOut.writeDouble(d);
                System.out.println("Writing " + b);
                dataOut.writeBoolean(b);
                System.out.println("Writing " + 12.2 * 7.4);
                dataOut.writeDouble(12.2 * 7.4);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try {
                    dataOut.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

and here is error :

```
 java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readDouble(Unknown Source)
    at bytestream.DataIOStream.readDataIOStream(DataIOStream.java:108)
    at bytestream.DataIOStream.main(DataIOStream.java:16)
Writing 10
Writing 1023.56
Writing true
Writing 90.28
Reading 172003324
Reading 8.029891292620447E283
Reading true
```

Please help me why i can't read Data Input stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataOut.write(i)` only writes one byte. Yet you are reading an `int` doing `i = dataIn.readInt()` which is 4 bytes.

Therefore when trying to read the last element which is a `double`, there is only 5 bytes in the stream while it is trying to read 8 bytes (the length of a `double`), hence the exception.

Since you want to write/read an `int`, you need to call `dataOut.writeInt(i)` instead of `dataOut.write(i)`.

Comment: you are missing instead of `dataOut.write(i);`